# Can't run puppeteer in react app, Module not found: Can't resolve 'ws' when compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I was wondering if it was possible to run puppeteer in my react app. Whenever I try to run puppeteer in my react app I get "Module not found: Can't resolve 'ws'". I've tried installing ws but will still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer : You can't run puppeteer in react app.

React is a client side framework. which means it runs in browser.

While puppeteer is a NodeJS lib, it needs Node.js and runs on server side.

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.

Comment: Is there no way at all to run puppeteer in react?

Comment: @tsl001 no way. puppeteer runs a full Chrome. why do you need to run a Chrome in another Chrome?

Comment: It's for my program that automates checking out items from shops through a ui

Comment: so you actually need to manipulate DOM, you can search for some other lib. or run your puppeteer on a local server, and then serve data to your react app

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the above answer.  You cannot directly run Puppeteer on a react app.  React app is a frontend framework and you would need Puppeteer to run on a node js, server.  It's a simple "fix" and I wanted to explain it a little more than the answer above does.

The steps to get them to work together would be.

1. Setup an express server.  You can create an express server like so:
   Separate directory `reactServer`.  `Npm init` directory and `npm i express`.

In your express server you allocate a path

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/my-react-path', (req, res) => {
  // run any scripts you need here
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Then your react app will interact with your server like so:

```
localhost:5000/my-react-path
```

In the `my-react-path` you can create a function that fires up puppeteer and does all the things you want on the server side and it can return whatever results to React.  The above example is just to get you started it doesn't have anything related to puppeteer.