# Export function not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, export

I have been working on a shopping list application in React but have ran into a problem with exporting a regular JavaScript function from a file called webscrape.js into my react App.js I have tried multiple different ways of exporting but I keep getting this error.
Thanks to any help in advance.

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'readline' in
> 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Programming-Projects\Counter
> App\counter-app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node'

This is the end of my webscrape file where I export a test function

```
function testExport(){
  console.log("Test Export");
}

function testExport2(){
  console.log("Test Export 2");
}
export {testExport, testExport2}
```

This is the start of my App.js where I import and try using the function

```
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import PriceBar from "./components/pricebar";
import "./App.css";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import fs from 'fs';
import data from "./shoppingData.json";
import {testExport, testExport2} from "./webscrape.js";

//test export
testExport();
```

Comment: Maybe just removing the extension? `from "./webscrape";`

Comment: Has puppeteer ever worked in your project? If not, maybe it's related to this: [Can't run puppeteer in react app, Module not found: Can't resolve 'ws' when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60700861/1218980)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `export default {testExport, testExport2}`.

But, looking throught your errors, seems like the error it's related to puppeter. Do you have `puppteer` added to your node_modules? Did you make a `npm i`?

Comment: Yes I use puppeteer for my webscrapping

Comment: should I do ```npm i```

Comment: when I do ```export default {testExport, testExport2}``` it gets rid of the error but then I get this error in app.js ```Attempted import error: 'testExport' is not exported from './webscrape.js'```

Comment: `default` is irrelevant (even wrong in this case).

Comment: ok so what should I do then I have tried multiple ways of exporting and they all give the same error

Comment: The problem isn't in the way you're exporting, it's elsewhere, but it's unclear from your question, it's why it's important to provide an [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
export const testExport = () => {
  console.log("Test Export");
}

export const testExport2 = () => {
  console.log("Test Export 2");
}
```

Comment: doing that gives me this error ```Attempted import error: './webscrape.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'testExport').```